# CHECK Constraint based on a column value IN OTHER Table

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database, constraints

## SqlServer

Suppose I have 2 tables:

Table 1 - having column A

Table 2 - having column B [Bit] Not Null

Is it possible to have a Check Constraint, such that value of Column B can be "0", only when Column A is NOT NULL.

*OR put it other way, value of Column B can be "1", only when Column A is NULL.*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the null-or-not-ness of Column A forces the exact value of Column B - why are you *storing* column B at all? You can always compute it on demand from Column A. In general, you shouldn't store *derived* data.

Comment: Agree with you , but it is not possible at the moment. Is there chance to add such constraint?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that these tables are already related by a suitable foreign key, we can implement this check using a computed column and a new foreign key.

**Make sure you read to the end**

So if we have:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (
    Table1ID char(5) not null,
    ColumnA int null,
    constraint PK_Table1 PRIMARY KEY (Table1ID)
)
CREATE TABLE Table2 (
    Table2ID char(7) not null,
    Table1ID char(5) not null,
    ColumnB bit not null,
    constraint PK_Table2 PRIMARY KEY (Table2ID),
    constraint FK_Table2_Table1 FOREIGN KEY (Table1ID) references Table1 (Table1ID)
)
```

We can run this script:

```
alter table Table1 add
    ColumnBPrime as CAST(CASE WHEN ColumnA is NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as bit) PERSISTED
go
alter table Table1 add constraint UQ_Table1_WithColumnBPrime UNIQUE (Table1ID, ColumnBPrime)
go
alter table Table2 add constraint FK_Table2_Table1_CheckColumnB FOREIGN KEY (Table1ID, ColumnB) references Table1 (Table1ID,ColumnBPrime)
```

Hopefully you can see how this enforces the relationship between the two tables<sup>1</sup>.

---

**However, there's an issue**. In T-SQL, any DML statement may only make changes to *one* table. So there's no way to issue an update that both changes whether ColumnA is null or not *and* changes Column B to suit it.

This is another good reason not to have Column B in the database at all - it's derived information, and in our quest to ensure it always matches its definition, we'd have to always delete from Table 2, update Table 1 and re-insert in Table 2.

---

<sup>1</sup>It's now a matter of personal taste whether you remove the previous foreign key or leave it in place as the "real" one.

Comment: Thanks for taking time out to reply! Considering the option I have, I think It is better to rethink, and derive the value of column B. Once again, thanks for your help :)